# Is the $L^p$ limit of holomorphic functions holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f_n:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions for $G$ an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $f_n\in L^p(G)$ and that there exists $f\in L^p(G)$ such that $f_n\to f$ in the $L^p$-norm. Then does there exists a holomorphic function $g:G\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=g(z)$ almost everywhere?

I am curious about this both for the case of $1\leq p<\infty$ and $p=\infty$. All of the convergence theorems I could find for holomorphic functions where about uniform limits or uniform limits on compact subsets.

Comment: it's not hard to show using Cauchy integral representation and Holder (for $1 \le p  < \infty$ that $|f_k-f_m|_{D} \le C||f_k-f_m||_p$ where $D$ is any small disc included in $G$ st say the double of itself is also in $G$ so convergence in $L^p$ implies local uniform Cauchy hence local uniform convergence so the limit is analytic; for $p=\infty$ the result is obvious